# How to find out user is present in Sqlite Database using android?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-database

I am working on a login/register app just for training as I am a beginner everything is working except for a small problem but I don't know how to fix it , I tried searching but couldn't find anything
here is the part of my database.kt

```
   fun userPresent (user: String,pass: String):Boolean {
       val db = writableDatabase
       val query = "select * from $TABLE_NAME where username = $user and password = $pass"
       val cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null)

       if (cursor.count <= 0) {
           cursor.close()
           return false }
       cursor.close()
       return true }
```

mainactivity.kt

```
if (database.userPresent(user = username,pass = password)) {
                intent.putExtra("text", "Welcome , $username $password")
                startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(this,"Logged In Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Wrong Username/Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

My logCat Error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ss (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from user_table where username = ss and password = ss
at com.example.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.userPresent(DatabaseHelper.kt:52)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:49)
```

also I am not sure on why you have to close the cursor.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is **not** that you pass the arguments as Integer (you don't), but that the arguments are not recognized as `TEXT` literals because they are not enclosed in single quotes, so SQLite thinks they are column names.

The recommended way of passing the parameters to `rawQuery()` is this:

```
fun userPresent (user: String, pass: String): Boolean {
    val db = writableDatabase 
    val query = "select * from $TABLE_NAME where username = ? and password = ?"
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, arrayOf(user, pass))
    val result = cursor.count > 0
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return result
}
```

The placeholders `?` will take their values from the corresponding items of the array passed as the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` and you don't need to concatenate the single quotes so you avoid the risk of [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
 
After that and before the return statement you must close both the `Cursor` and the `db` object.

Answer (score 0):

The final query should be like below

```
select * from user_table where username = 'ss' and password = 'ss';
```

Wrap your username and password with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that your user and pass variables are **String**
and you must put your String variables

into  **" "**  or  **'  '**

But You put them as **Integer** while your table columns (user and pass) are not Integer and They are **String**

Use String arguments and put your `user` and `pass` variables in it.
It will help you you to solve your problem.

```
val query="select * from $TABLE_NAME where username =? and password = ?"
val arguments= arrayOf(user, pass)
db.rawQuery(query, arguments)
```

Of course as the Second way you can try this too

```
val query="select * from $TABLE_NAME where username = \'$user\' and password = \'$pass\'"
db.rawQuery(query, null)
```