# How to identify exception with SQLite database query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to type the code to be able to disable the button when the data is already in sqlite. But I found this error instead! Can you help me to find a solution?

```
public boolean isExist(MovieFav movie) {
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIE + " WHERE " + _ID + "=" + movie.getTitle();

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

**And this is an error that I got**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.submission4madegdk2019, PID: 16246
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Joker (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM movie_favorites WHERE
>   _id=Joker
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1392)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
>           at com.example.submission4madegdk2019.db.MovieFavHelper.isExist(MovieFavHelper.java:104)
>           at com.example.submission4madegdk2019.activity.DetailMovieActivity.onClick(DetailMovieActivity.java:158)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

**And this is the code**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        if (movieFavHelper.isExist(movieFav)){
            btnSaveMov.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnSaveMov.setEnabled(true);
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_love) {

            String titles = tv_title.getText().toString().trim();
            String overview = tv_overview.getText().toString().trim();
            String release_date = tv_release.getText().toString().trim();
            String vote_average = tv_vote_average.getText().toString().trim();

            String url_poster = tv_url_image.getText().toString().trim();

            movieFav.setTitle(titles);
            movieFav.setOverview(overview);
            movieFav.setRelease_date(release_date);
            movieFav.setVote_average(vote_average);
            movieFav.setPoster_path(url_poster);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(SEND_MOVIE_FAV, movieFav);
            intent.putExtra(SEND_POSITION, position);


            if (!isInsert) {
                if (!movieFavHelper.isExist(movieFav)) {

                    long result = movieFavHelper.insertMovie(movieFav);

                    if (result > 0) {

                        setResult(RESULT_ADD, intent);
                        Toast.makeText(DetailMovieActivity.this, getString(R.string.success_add), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        btnSaveMov.setEnabled(false);
                        Toast.makeText(DetailMovieActivity.this, getString(R.string.failed_add), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The value `Joker` being a String (not a column name) would need to be quoted **but** you are better off using a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: `WHERE _id=Joker` should be like this `WHERE _id = 'Joker'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out user is present in Sqlite Database using android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152742/how-to-find-out-user-is-present-in-sqlite-database-using-android)

Comment: Even though you have a purpose--to disable a button--by getting data from a database, it is important to realize that the error and the problem really have nothing to do with the button.  **The problem is all about the database code.**  You can program the button to do whatever you like once the database code is working.  The title of the question is about the button, but the details are about the database.  This is important not only for those helping you, but you can better debug code when recognizing what component or code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is critical to properly interpret exception (i.e. error) details.  If you cannot do that, then you cannot properly debug your code.  Dumps of exception details can get messy, but here are the key points.  Notice that the type of exception and the overall problem are described by

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Joker (code 1)

SQLite is expecting to find a column called Joker.  But why?  To answer that, there is another clue in the exception details:

> SELECT * FROM movie_favorites WHERE _id=Joker

The rest of the exception details are just about the code trace and are not helpful since you already know the code which has the problem.  So let's look at the details of the SQL which caused the problem:

```
... WHERE _id=Joker
```

SQLite will interpret `Joker` as a column, because it is not wrapped in quotes like a string.  But since it is not a column in the table, SQLite has no idea what `Joker` is.  It doesn't know that you mean to match the movie name.  Really, a string should be wrapped in quotes, something like `'Joker'` so that SQLite knows that it is a string.

If we analyze it even further, we see that it is trying to compare a column named `_id` to the name of a movie.  But most of the time (really all the time except is weird cases), a name like `_id` is an integer primary key.  My guess is that this query is comparing the wrong column completely.  Here is just a guess at what the proper SQL should look like... only a guess:

```
SELECT * FROM movie_favorites WHERE movie_title = 'Joker'
```

To get that result, you either need to fix the existing code to include the proper column and to wrap `movie.getTitle()` in quotes...

OR

Even better would be to use proper **SQL query parameters** (prepared statements) to avoid SQL injection and other bugs... like if the move title contains quotes.  How to do that cannot be answered here since a full tutorial is beyond the scope of this question, but it can be discovered by searching elsewhere for *"how to use sql parameters in java"*.

Once this bug is fixed, the button code may work just fine.  But if it doesn't then you research that bug separately and possibly ask a new question.